# Insert into select with new value

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to copy the data of a table to an new table and add an extra value to it? So, I would like to use this query:

`INSERT INTO database2.table1 (field2,field3) SELECT table2.field2,table2.field3 FROM table2;`

but would also add a new variable, for example a date field: `date=now()`

Comment: It's possible. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming table1 has the same field as table2 plus a field `date`:

```
INSERT INTO db.table1 (`field1`, `field2`, `date`)
SELECT 
  `field1`,
  `field2`,
  NOW() as `date`
FROM db.table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done.try like this :

```
INSERT INTO database2.table1(field2,field3, date) 
SELECT table2.field2,table2.field3,now() AS date
FROM table2
```